# Converting an object into Dynamic with JSON.Net

Tags: serialization, json.net

What I'm wanting to do, is take an object construct (For example, an Entity Framework object), then convert it to a dynamic object (Thinking JSON.Net JObject may be the best fit), and extending said object with additional properties for sending to the client, or a View template.

```
dynamic model = JS.ToJObject(myConcreteInstance);
model.AdditionalValue = "I need this stuff on the client... ";
```

Here's what I have, which works, but would rather not have the try/catch.

```
//JS.ToJObject
public static JObject ToJObject(object input)
{
    try {
        //anonymous types throw an exception here
        //    Could not determine JSON object type for type f__AnonymousType ...
        return new JObject(input);
    } catch(Exception) {
        //fallback to serialize/deserialize, which seems wasteful
        var txt = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
            input
            ,new IsoDateTimeConverter()
            ,new DataTableConverter()
            ,new DataSetConverter()
        );
        return JObject.Parse(txt);
    }
}
```